# Eclipse change focused text color

Tags: eclipse, colors

someone knows how to change in Eclipse, focused text color?
Like in the linked image:
https://ibb.co/2spChFd
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All the appearance change in eclipse can be doe from 
Windows> Preferences> General> Appearance>

- more info can be found in the [link to eclipse fonts and color change](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Faccessibility%2Ffontsandcolors.htm)

Answer (score 0):

In *Window > **Preferences: General > Editors > Text Editors*** in section *Appearance color options* select ***Selection background color***, disable *System Default* and choose the color you want.